# UITableViewCell not displaying my data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my TableViewController, I set my TableViewCell through the storyboard. And in the method `…cellForRowAtIndexPath` I do

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"my_identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  UILabel *myTitle = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
  UITextView *myDetail = (UITextView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
  //…more stuff
  myTitle.text = item.title;
  myDetail.text = item.detail;
  return cell;
}
```

When I set my TableViewCell in the storyboard I set the tags through the attribute inspector. Anyway, at this point I am logging everything through NSLog so that I know that my data exist, `myTitle` indeed contains the title, etc, etc. For example the following logging works

```
NSLog(@“my title after passing it to myTitle is %@“, myTitle.text);
```

So I am logging all over. But for whatever reason the cell is not showing in the table when I run the code. It keeps saying that there is no data.

The only thing that makes sense at this point is that, for instance, `myTitle` is not a pointer to the title contained in the cell. So is there a way to set the content of `myTitle` back to the cell? I know I am missing something. I just can’t tell what it is.

**Update**

So I create a subclass of UITableViewCell per [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnzkcV_XUw8). Still logging everything, my logging shows that everything should be working fine, but the table is still not showing anything. except for “No Result”. It’s as if the cell does not belong to the table and yet it’s there in the Document Outline: Table View > View > Custom Table View Cell — my_identifier > Content View > [my children views]

Comment: I know this isn't on-topic to your issue - just a general suggestion. Why not use IBOutlet properties on your `CustomTableViewCell`? You can create an IBOutlet for a UILabel, call it myTitle, and put it as a property in `CustomTableViewCell`. Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, you can use cell.myTitle instead of doing `viewWithTag`.

Comment: @LyricalPanda what you are saying might work, but how would I "put it as a property in CustomTableViewCell"? I am thinking about it, but I don't see it. I am happy to abandon the tag stuff if this will fix the problem.

Comment: Some ideas:

Make sure you have registered the cell for reuse with the table. If it's a prototype cell in a storyboard, be sure to give it an identifier. Double check the cell's identifier in interface builder. Try to give us the code that is dequeuing the cell so others an possibly pinpoint the problem

Comment: @KatedralPillon This won't fix your issue, just a suggestion to help keep your code a little easier to maintain and use the power of IBOutlets since you're using storyboard. Here is an album of what it looks like: http://imgur.com/a/r9ECf#0. It shows adding it as a property to the .h, making sure the property on the UITableViewCell in Storyboard is linked to the UILabel, and then how to use it inside the cellForRow.

Comment: @iFeli you make it sounds like a two step process. I thought by setting the Identifier the cell is set for reuse. Is there another place to set it for reuse?

Comment: It depends on how you are using it. If you are using it from a XIB or  programmatically, you need to register the NIB or class for reuse on the table view. If it's a prototype cell inside a storyboard, then you simply set the cell's identifier and dequeue it.

It just depends on what mechanism you are using to create/retrieve your cell.

Comment: There seems to be a `tableView` versus a `self.tableView` thing going on. I am using a `Search Bar and Search Display Controller`. Since I am doing no filtering I largely ignore the distinction. But should I have applied the distinction inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? I don't really think that's a problem since the logging shows the child views are inflated without any problem. The problem seems to be that they do not connect back to the cell.

Comment: @LyricalPanda it looks like the tag thing is not working. I try using a tag number that I never assigned and everything still works fine. So I want to use your technique. But I don't get it: I can't get `Connection Inspector to show a connection such as your `nameLabel. I drag connections from the storyboard to the `.h`. So I guess the step I am missing is "put it as a property in CustomTableViewCell". So how do I make a UILabel into a property of a TableViewCell? Do I have to programmatically call `addSubview`?

Comment: Create a UITableViewCell subclass, and add a nameLabel IBOutlet property in it. In IB, change the class of your cell to your subclass, and then you can connect the outlet to the label.

Comment: @KatedralPillon Saw the update, please post screenshots of your Storyboard so we can make sure everything is linked properly. Also I don't know if it makes a difference but I use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` without the indexPath. Take a look at this image to see how I typically create the cells http://imgur.com/a/r9ECf#2.

Answer (score 0):

Create IBOutlet for your `tableView` in .h file and `@synthesize` it in .m file

Add the following codes inside `viewWillAppear`

```
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.delegate = self;
[tableView reloadData];
```

For the cell in your table, make sure that your label is connected with cell

And your label is linked as one `IBOutlet` in .h file, also `@synthesize` in .m file

[image: drag your label to your cell]

or simply initialise and create your label inside the cell's `contentView`:

```
UILabel * mytitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 25)];
mytitle.text = item.title;
mytitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview mytitle];
```

Comment: If you use `@property` you don't have to do `@synthesize`.